# Div is being appended with duplicate data

Tags: jquery

I was struck on a big issue where i see that the same data is being shown multiple times

Once clicked on  a href tag , this function will get called (which will append data to a div)

```
$(document).on("click", ".secclass a", function (e) {
if(whetherchecked)
  {
var name = $(this).attr("name");
var topping='<div class="Topping-details"><section><i id="topping-close"></i><a href="#">'+name+'</a></section></div>';

        $("#myordersdiv ul").append(topping);
        clcik++;
        $("#myordersdiv").find("i.totalorders").text(clcik);
        $("#myordersdiv").show();

    }
});
```

Similarly when checked on a checkbox , i am adding orders to the same div

```
$(document).on("click", ".checkboxclas", function(e) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        wqhetherchecked = true;
        var buildcart = $('<div id="addtoordersdiv"></div>');
        buildcart.append('<div  data-role="collapsible"><div class="prd-items-detials"><ul><li class="head"><form><label class="testtt" for="checkbox-mini-0">' + itemname + '</label></form></li><li class="prd-items-qt"></div>');
        var dataa = '<div id="ordersdiv" style="display:none"></div>';

        $("#myordersdiv ul").append(dataa);
        $("#ordersdiv").prepend(buildcart);
        clcik++;
        $("#myordersdiv").find("i.myorderhead22").text(clcik);
        $("#myordersdiv").show();
    } else {
        $('#addtoordersdiv').remove();
        clcik--;
        $("#myordersdiv").find("i.myorderhead22").text(clcik);
    }
});
```

As a result of this the div is being appended with duplicate data , could you please tell me how to resolve this ??

Comment: In your second code segment `wqhetherchecked` is spelled differently than in your first.  I would really need to see the HTML you are looking at to know more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have more than one element with the class .checkboxclas, there could be a problem later in the code (when you modify elements) since you only use $(this) to check for checked.

$("#myordersdiv ul").append(dataa); appends dataa to all uls that are within #myordersdiv.

Also, whenever you check a box, you create #ordersdiv (dataa) but when you uncheck, you don't delete it.